# Password Protect wp-login from httpd.conf, breaks .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress

I run a shared hosting server with a few hundred wordpress sites and I want to put htpasswd on the login form. So I tried this in my httpd.conf:

```
<Files wp-login.php>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Password Protected Area"
        AuthUserFile /var/htpass/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
</Files>
```

It nearly wprks, but most sites it causes an infinite redirect. If I delete the .htaccess from the site this works, but that breaks pretty URLs. Any ideas how I can make these both work together? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

snippet of my wordpress:

```
<LocationMatch "/(wp-(admin|comments\-post|cron|login)|xmlrpc)(\/|\.php)?.*">
    <Limit GET POST>
        ACL-GOES-HERE
    </Limit>
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would put the password protection in the .htaccess file itself instead of httpd.conf

```
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Wordpress Login Page"

<Files "wp-login.php">
  Require valid-user
</Files>
```